# Uint8Array byteoffset and unsigned char*

Tags: c++, webassembly

In this function (https://github.com/migerh/wasm-filter/blob/master/filter.js):

```
function filter(imageData) {
    const bufferPointerIn = 1024,
        {data, width, height} = imageData,
        bufferIn = new Uint8Array(wasmModule.memory.buffer, bufferPointerIn, width * height * 4),
        bufferPointerOut = 2048 + width * height * 4,
        bufferOut = new Uint8Array(wasmModule.memory.buffer, bufferPointerOut, width * height * 4);

    bufferIn.set(data);
    wasmModule.outline_c(bufferPointerIn, bufferPointerOut, width, height);
    data.set(bufferOut);
    return data;
}
```

`bufferPointerIn` and `bufferPointerOut` are basically `byteoffset` according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array

How it can be used as a pointer? I mean how an integer in javascript can be understood as `unsigned char*` in C. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wasmModule.memory.buffer` is a buffer representing the WASM module's memory. That is, from the C program's point of view, the value at address X will be whatever is at index X of `wasmModule.memory.buffer`.

So anything that is a valid index for `wasmModule.memory.buffer` (i.e. any integer between 0 (inclusive) and `wasmModule.memory.buffer.byteLength` (exclusive)) would be a valid memory address for the C program.

Since you use `bufferPointerIn` and `bufferPointerOut` both as the pointers passed to the C function as well as the offsets for the `Uint8Array`s, this means that what's in those arrays will correspond to the contents of the memory at those addresses (from the C program's point of view).